# Is Crystal Reports faster than calling SQL Query inside Visual Basic?

Tags: sql, vb.net, performance, crystal-reports

My colleague told me today that it is faster to use Crystal Reports when generating reports than directly embedding SQL Queries inside VB code.

He told me in VB one needs to filter a lot of things in order to generate the reports, and the code will be quite complicated, but Crystal Reports can create some formula to do the calculation process easily and faster, and you need to only call the formula. Here, the system performance will be better, and reports can be loaded faster.

Does not Crystal Reports at the end of the day translate to SQL Query? So what makes it more performant if ever so?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the data access goes, you could write code that is slower than what Crystal would generate. But if you could generate the result set in a stored procedure then I doubt you would see any difference either way. And if you are able to do the query logic in Crystal, then you could definitely do it in a stored procedure.
But as far as the UI, you don't want to try to create a report unless all you need is a straight forward grid. Reporting tools provide grouping, summing, drilling, paging, exporting, etc that are wheels you don't want to reinvent. 
Crystal Reports as a program is great, but Crystal reports embedded in .Net applications are notoriously difficult, fragile and error prone. 
ANY other reporting tool is better than Crystal for embedding in .Net, including Microsoft reports, either server reports (.rdl) or local reports (.rdlc).

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to say, Crystal report is used a reporting tool and it is not free.

Now for the performance point of view, if your data is very simple to show, Good to use VB.net code. Also as @Crowcoder tell, if you generate the data from Procedure is very good.

Crystal report have facility and used to create a complex report which you can or may not simple via VB.net code.